# Android Fragment Unable to Extends ListFragment Class. [App Not Running]

Tags: android

I am building an Android App that will use 3 Fragment, I have three Classes, MainActivity, SectionPagerAdapter and Section1Fragment Class, There is No error Warning in the Code but the App is not Running. Below are the Code, Please help.

**MAINACTIVITY CLASS**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter( this,getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }




}
```

****SECTIONPAGERADAPTER CLASS****

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;



/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    protected Context context1;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context ,FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        context=context1;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return new Section1Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return context1.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return context1.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return context1.getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SECTION1FRAGMENT CLASS**

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Section1Fragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Section1Fragment extends ListFragment but you use a RelativeLayout instead of a ListView. If you do `public class Section1Fragment extends Fragment` instead
you should be good to go.

Comment: If i import android.app.ListFragment; The SectionPagerAdapter Constructor will get an Unmatch Error,  While the MainActivity oncreat() Method will be throw an error too.

Comment: @Kriz_bus no big deal. I'm fairly new and would need to test it myselfe to find out whats wrong. Do you mind adding your xml files?

Comment: Check the file Below>>

Comment: @Kriz_bus i edited my answere. That should solve the problem. :)

Comment: Hi, Spirit009, Am still having the Same problem.. Thanks, If i remove the extends to Listfragment, the app will run, but i need to list item  inside the fragment using Adapter which extends to list..

Comment: in that case you have to add a ListView with the id attribute android.R.id.list

Comment: Great, It works, perfectly, Do you know how to move the Tabs from Top to Down in the Layout? Thanks

Comment: are you talking about having the action bar at the bottom?

Comment: No. I mean. I have three Tabs position below the man action bar at the top. How can i position it at the bottom . Just like the instagram Tabs if you use  the app. I tried editing the fragment codes but got some warning.

Comment: i cant really help you with that one i've never done something like that.

Comment: since i helped you it would be kinda nice if you could mark my answhere as the correct one =) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Xml Files?

**activity_Main XML**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.snapmatch.MainActivity" />
```

**fragment_main.xml FILE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.snapmatch.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```